# Just missing on Apple PHP configuration using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, macos, apache

I'm trying to rework a legacy site by converting .html to .php for ease of future configuration.  To accomplish this I'm working within the Apache server on my Mac OS X 10.9 machine.  I've written an users.conf file uses mod_rewrite to remap the file names ending in .html to run as .php.

It was working fine when I left work yesterday, but today I get a "You don't have permission to access" error on the front end and a "[error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration:" on the back end when I try to access localhost/~user/somefile.html.php  All of the file permissions are set correctly (644 or 755 as appropriate).

Seems to only happen with files named somefile.html.php.  Files named .html load fine and files named .php load fine.  Apache version is 2.2.24.

Here is user.conf:

```
<Directory "/Users/user/Sites/mySite">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/Users/user/Sites/mySite">
           RewriteEngine on
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
           RewriteRule ^(.*\.html) $1.php
</Directory>
```

And here is relevant part of httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/user/Sites"
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/Users/user/Sites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Maybe I've mixed together too many tutorials?

Comment: Earned the tumbleweed badge.  Sweet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I also needed to configure a virutal host.

[This particular guide gave me the final clue I needed.](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/set-virtual-hosts-apache-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-osx-10-8-mountain-lion/)